# Different screw/screw hole size on tripod/tripod head

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, compatibility

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I have a tripod (cheap, Chinese, bought on Amazon) and I wanted to change the ball-head it came with to a 3-way head, so I bought a Velbon PH-157Q head.

When I unscrewed the ball-head from my tripod I saw this screw: [image: http://postimg.org/image/c23ely0kf/]

...which is obviously the right size for the head I just unscrewed, but too big for the screw hole on my new Velbon head:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/ooh68trxx/]

Basically...how can I screw the new head onto this tripod? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an adapter such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YMMJFLC) (or [this alternate one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CAMVATE-Female-Conversion-Tripod-Adapter/dp/B01MEH1X42), or [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Metal-Adapter-conversion-Screw-3-8-female-to-1-4-male-fr-tripod-head-camera/170971414563?_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIM.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D41376%26meid%3Deb33d9e1b1c748b9a2b48e0bfda3fdfc%26pid%3D100011%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D12%26mehot%3Dpp%26sd%3D181544167593&_trksid=p2047675.c100011.m1850)) that has a 3/8-16 hole on one side and a 1/4-20 screw on the other.

[image]

You can get them [without the large flat circle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BPCMRW), but they are more for adapting light stands and such. For a head on a tripod the larger round base will provide more stability, which is the whole point of a tripod.

From the comments below:

> Actually, it looks like maybe all you need to do is remove the adapter that's already in the head... see that slot for turning it? Actually, on second look, the insert seems a little big for that, but... check it out.

and

> All we can see of the brass insert is the head -- there's no way to tell what size socket it fits into. I agree with @junkyardsparkle that the slots cut into the insert are clearly meant to let you unscrew it. I'd try a large flathead screwdriver rather than a coin.

and

> always possible that the brass insert has the equivalent of a bolt
>   head to stop you screwing it too far in... Looks like it's clearly
>   intended to be removable, so I'd try unscrewing it before splashing
>   out on an adapter that may not be needed.

Based on Tom W's review under the review tab of the [Velbon PH-157Q at Adorama](https://www.adorama.com/vnph157qbk.html), if the 1/4-20 insert is removed another insert with 3/8-16 threads must be used:

> works as advertised; **had bit of a tussle trying to get 3/8-16 bushing shipped**, as advertised, but Customer service came thru- finally ... suggest you confirm available bushing sizes B4 ordering this item ...

Comment: Actually, it looks like *maybe* all you need to do is remove the adapter that's already *in* the head... see that slot for turning it? Actually, on second look, the insert seems a little big for that, but... check it out.

Comment: [Manufacturer page](http://www.velbon.biz/product/head.html) says it has a 3/8 socket...

Comment: That brass insert in the bottom of the head is a lot larger than 3/8 if the hole is 1/4.

Comment: @junkyardsparkle can you provide a direct link to that specification? Your link only takes one to the page for the Velbon PHD-66Q, and the spec there appears to refer to the screw on top of the quick release plate, not the hole on the bottom for attaching it to the tripod legs.

Comment: You have to click on the "panhead" tab after the link, sorry. It does look big, but threaded stuff can be deceptive that way... but possibly they use an insert for 3/8 models, too.

Comment: 3/8 is only 1/8 (50%) wider than 1/4 (2/8). That insert is at least 3 times the width of the hole.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replies. I did try to remove the adapter with the slot in it (just using a coin) but it seemed impossible to unscrew it and I didn't want to force it using a tool in case I damaged it. I was hoping there could just be some kind of adapter I could buy, so now I know exactly what I need, that helps a lot. Cheers.

Comment: All we can see of the brass insert is the head -- there's no way to tell what size socket it fits into. I agree with @junkyardsparkle that the slots cut into the insert are clearly meant to let you unscrew it. I'd try a large flathead screwdriver rather than a coin.

Comment: @MichaelClark Your first link seems to be broken.

Comment: @Calab, a lot of Amazon links went dead at midnight last night. Maybe it will come back on line.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a couple of other links and a photo.

Comment: always possible that the brass insert has the equivalent of a bolt head to stop you screwing it too far in... Looks like it's clearly intended to be removable, so I'd try unscrewing it before splashing out on an adapter that may not be needed.

Comment: @JerryTheC It's obvious the insert in the replacement head is much larger than 3/8". It's more like 3/4". If one managed to remove it one would need another insert with a 3/8-16 hole in it. It would be more difficult to determine exactly what one needed (exact size and thread pitch of the hole with the insert removed vs. the known size and thread pitch of the hole in the existing insert) and probably more difficult to find such an insert vs. a standardized 3/8-16 female to 1/4-20 male adapter. And we're only talking a $5 part!

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for the ping, I forgot about this question, but in the meantime I've seen a few inserts just like this one. Posting an answer so I can add a picture.

Answer (score 2):

While it sounds like it may not be true in this particular case, some heads with 3/8" native threads come with installed bushings to adapt to 1/4", and can appear to be larger than 3/8" due to a flange on the bottom. If you can't determine otherwise from the specs, it's probably worth checking before resorting to adding yet another adapter (and possible point of failure).

[image]
This is a one such adapter I've encountered.

Comment: It may well be that the insert has a flange head (which is totally different from a bolt head as mentioned by Jerry C to a comment on the other answer), but if so the one pictured in the OP is still significantly larger in diameter than the one pictured in your answer. Based on a review by Tom W. in the PH-157Q head's listing at Adorama, a different bushing (insert) with 3/8-16 threads is needed, rather than the hole under the 1/4-20 insert being threaded at 3/8-16.

Comment: That seems strange, but I'll take your word for it... maybe it's an attempt to shift towards a more robust and/or metric standard? I'll leave the answer as it may be useful for other cases, but I'll edit it to clarify that it may not always be the case.

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with the grade of aluminum used for the head's body. Softer metals require larger threads to tolerate the same amount of torque. One solution in many applications is to use steel inserts threaded into larger holes in aluminum.